# Appropriate to email the HR manager if a higher/supervisory position is available?

Tags: recruitment

The company I wish to work for is currently doing major recruitment (i.e trying to fill plenty of positions) in my city.
This company is extremely well known, and is great for future career development.

I have supervisory experience in this industry, however the position listed is only entry level.

Is it appropriate to drop a line to the HR manager enclosing my CV, explaining that I would be interested in a supervisory position due to my experience, and ask if I could be considered for one?

If so, how could I word my email to explain as such?

Thanks again!

Comment: It's likely pointless to do so, because if they had supervisory positions open to external hires, they would list them as well.

Comment: @jpatokal It’s very well possible they do not openly list them but go through head hunters for that level or mostly hire via references from current employees.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it appropriate to drop a line to the HR manager enclosing my CV, explaining that I would be interested in a supervisory position due to my experience, and ask if I could be considered for one?

The odds are slim if they're not listing it, but sure, if this is a company you particularly want to work for, why not? I'd just fire off a quick email saying that you've seen they're hiring, and ask if they have any senior positions open for `x`.

It only takes a couple of minutes, and the worst you get is a negative reply / no reply. The only thing I'd caution against is chasing them if they don't reply quickly or at all - you don't want to come off as desperate, as that could potentially negatively affect your chances if you were to apply for a listed position at that company in the future.